# A special linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Does there exist infinite dimensional vector space $V$ with a linear transformation on $V$ such that $\operatorname{nullity}T=\operatorname{rank} T = \dim V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the real vector spaces of terminal sequences, that is $V=\left\{(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mid \exists M\in \mathbb{N}: a_n=0, \forall n\geq N\right\}$. A basis for space is given by the standard sequences $e_i\in V$, i.e. $(e_i)_j=\delta_{ij}$. Now define a map $T$ by $T(e_{2i+1})=e_{2i+1}$ and $T(e_{2i})=0$. This map $T$ satisfies the claim.

Edit: This is almost the exact same example as Martin Argerami gave you but there is one difference. The vector space of terminal sequences has a countable basis whereas the vector space of bounded sequences has an uncountable basis. This might complicate certain calculations and reasonings as you can not find a basis for the bounded sequences explicitly (it uses the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $V=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, and let $T$ be given by 
$$
Tx=(x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,0,\ldots).
$$
Then both the kernel and the rank of $T$ are infinite-dimensional subspaces of $V$, each isomorphic to $V$.

Comment: Ah, basically the same example, you were faster than me though :)